# Computer vision tool to match regions in two images at different pixel locations

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have two image files. One image has subplots of (100) stock price graphs with stock ticker labels. The other image has subplots of (112) stock price graphs shuffled to a different row and column in the image with a unique numeric id. 100 of the 112 stock ids are from the first image. The time periods in both the images are identical. I would like to match the graph patterns so that I can map the ticker to the unique numeric id. Is there any online computer vision tool that can do this? Maybe a free online computer vision tool on the web? I want to just upload these two images and want the matches to be found out. I have attached the two iamges for your convenience. The graphs cannot be matched by color they have to be matched by price movement patterns only.

For example: ticker symbol, AMZN is matched with numeric id, 61. ticker symbol GE is matched by numeric id 31.

> Subplots with ticker symbol given

[image]

> Subplots with unique numeric id

[image]

> Note: the subplots CANNOT be matched by color. they have to be matched
> by price movements